A son goes to court to stop his old father from marrying a young woman
I saw this film on TV in the 1980s.
A man asked a judge to stop his funny old millionaire father marrying a young woman on grounds that his old father is mentally incapacitated and the young woman only wants his father's money.
The old man represents himself and refuses to retain the services of a lawyer. He annoys the judge by saying "I rest my case!" at the end of argument he makes.
His son calls a psychiatrist as an expert witness to say his father is not mentally capable to taking the decision to get married. The old man tackles the psychiatrist by giving him a challenge: he should provide a funny punch line to a sentence the old man makes. The reasoning is only a sane person could provide such a punch line. The psychiatrist's punch line is not funny. However, the old man provides a funny punch line, which the judge and the courtroom like. The psychiatrist agrees the old man is mentally sound.
The beautiful young woman says she loves the old man and wants to marry him because he is funny.
To prove that it is indeed possible for two people to fall in love and be happily married upon a chance meeting, the old man describes the following: a man makes a joke to a waitress who's just served him. The waitress laughs. The man proposes to her right away. The waitress accepts without hesitation. They get married.
The old man asks his son if such a marriage could be happy. The son says such a marriage was doomed to fail. The old man informs him that was how he (the old man) met his son's mother. Yet, the marriage was a happy one.
With the judge's nod of approval, the old man ends his submission and declares, "I rest my case!"
The judge's judgement is the old man is mentally competent to get married. The delighted old man pleads with the judge to marry them right away since he was convinced his son would appeal. The judge agrees.
I used to think the old man was George Burns, but I think I'm wrong since I couldn't trace the movie George Burns' filmography.

This could be the rather forgotten TV movie Marriage Is Alive and Well from 1980.

A photographer [played by  Joe Namath?!] who specializes in weddings and who, according to others, has the perfect marriage. However, he and his wife are at a crossroad and have decided to separate. While he and his wife bicker and she prepares to leave, he reminisces about people whom he has photographed who have had unusual relationships. A couple has married, gotten divorced, married again, divorced again and have run into each other again. A young couple who have just gotten married after living together, which the bride prefers. And an aging comic who wants to marry a young girl over the objections of his son.

The rich comedian wants to marry his secretary who's 60 years younger than him, and his son does all he can to prevent it. Sadly, there's not a lot of information about it; there's an online clip, but it's from a different story. Maybe the actors will jog your memory. The comedian was played by Jack Albertson (Grandpa Joe from Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory):

And the judge was played by Mel Stewart:

Here's the VHS:


Sorry, this is not the movie!

@FelleyMoore Ah, sorry about that. What about the other one?

Neither of them is. I'm trying to edit the question, add a little detail here and there to see if that would help. Thanks, anyway.

@FelleyMoore Really? I'm surprised. Romance on the Orient Express fits every single detail...

It appears by "other one" you mean my other question about the two lovers on the train? Just guessed from your comment. You are right: the answer to "the other one" is Romance on the Orient Express. Thought I already marked that as "solved".

Walt, I responded to your comment but I can't see it. So, here goes. I didn't know your "other one" meant Romance on the Orient Express. Yes, the "other one" is IT. Thanks.

@FelleyMoore Cool, sorry for the confusion. But if you're satisfied with an answer, don't forget to approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it. That way other people would instantly know that it's solved.

You know, the more I look at the pictures you posted, the more I think maybe I should attempt to find more information on "Marriage Is Alive and Well". I might not have watched the movie from the beginning so perhaps it is indeed the movie. I'll work more on getting info on it. Thanks.

Well, I hope you find it. It's a bit obscure.

I believe the movie the OP is referring to is the 1994 comedy, Greedy, which stars Kirk Douglas as the ageing millionaire  Uncle Joe Mcteague, who apparently falls for his much younger nurse, played by Nancy Travis...

Movie synopsis

Uncle Joe is ageing. He's also a millionaire. That's why his family is trying so very hard to get into his good books. They all want a piece of his empire. Unfortunately Uncle Joe isn't as stupid as his family thinks he is. He can see that his family is only nice to him because they want his money. Along comes Daniel McTeague, a struggling bowler, imported from another city by his family, to put an end to this ridiculous situation. The fight won't be easy, though, because the poor family has a little bit of competition - A beautiful nurse who takes care of Uncle Joe (and no doubt would love to take care of his bank account). 


Then again, maybe not...

@WumpusQ.Wumbley I think not either, Nancy Travis must have been the grandson's (Michael J. Fox) girlfriend then. Well sometimes memories play tricks on us, the OP could be mixing up two movies.... I know it happens to me! I should probably delete this answer.

Sorry, this is not the movie. I believe the movie was in the 80s: not the 90s. Thanks. Still open...

Ahh, the  "upvote a wrong answer" just so the bot doesn't bump this  question any more. That's one way of handling things :)
